# Is there a way to report when a field was last populated?

Tags: reporting, custom-field, page-layout, fields, reports-api

I want to see if a field is obsolete, meaning if it is not populated with data in the last six months, I would like to hide it from the page layout. 
So, Is there a way where I can run a report or find out when a field was last updated?

Appreciate your answers on this.

Comment: If  you had enabled tracking on certain fields, after a period of time you may run a history report and find out when the field was last updated by sorting the edit date. But if you do not have tracking there may be third party apps other people in the community may know. Nothing out of box that I know which gives you such info

Comment: You can also check this and other useful info using audit trails.

Comment: You can run Salesforce Optimizer from setup
[Check this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/175832/91175)

Answer (score 0):

You can run Salesforce Optimizer from setup.

Salesforce Optimizer analyzes a suite of features and sends you a personalized report about how you can improve your implementation. You can run Optimizer for both sandbox and production environments.
Just search for unused fields per object section or field usage.