# Find fields that are not in use

Tags: custom-field

**Scenario**

In my grown org (200 objects, thousands of fields) some fields are not in use. We define as not in use by the following criteria: (A) No records for the whole object or (B) not populated within the last 6 months.

**Question**

1. Is there any way to determine field without value and modified within the last 6 months?
2. What is the best approach to find the fields?

Comment: I am also struggling with this. I have launched Salesforce Optimizer but never get a selection of production or sandbox. Just a popup saying my org is being analyzed. I never get a report. It's very strange. Any ideas what ma be going on? I have all the correct permissions.

Comment: For me also Optimizer didn't send the report. But when I went to my org and check the 'Files' it's there.

Answer (score 7):

One native way is to run Salesforce Optimizer from setup

> Salesforce Optimizer analyzes a suite of features and sends you a
>   personalized report about how you can improve your implementation. You
>   can run Optimizer for both sandbox and production environments.

You will get a personalized report on your instance. Specific to your requirement you will get fields related statistics -
[image: Field Usage - Optimizer]

For e.g. unused fields -
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The folks at Qandor developed a great app called  [Field Trip](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KaYJ) perfect for the job. And even better, it is free! This tool analyzes both standard and custom fields across all objects and tells you how many records each field is populated in and the percentage of records that have that field populated.

More info is avaialbe on [USING FIELD TRIP APP TO CLEAN UP YOUR SALESFORCE INSTANCE](http://cloud4good.com/announcements/using-field-trip-app-tp-clean-up-your-salesforce-instance/)