# What is the best practice for cleaning up unused fields or fields that haven't been used in a long time?

Tags: metadata, field-history, cleanup

I have been tasked with cleaning up fields across our org that are not in use or haven't been used in some time period. For each field of an object, I want to know when the last time its value was updated on a record (NOT when the configuration of the field was updated). I have tried apps like FieldTrip and FieldPro, but these only show me the last date when the config of the field was changed. I am currently tracking a subset of fields, then manually checking field history for the last update date, but I am limited to 20/object at a time and this doesn't seem very efficient. Does anyone have better recommendations or an easier way that I can determine unused fields?

Answer (score 0):

One native way is to run Salesforce Optimizer from setup

Salesforce Optimizer analyzes a suite of features and sends you a personalized report about how you can improve your implementation. You can run Optimizer for both sandbox and production environments.

You will get a personalized report on your instance. Specific to your requirement you will get fields related statistics.

For more information, refer this link :- [Find fields that are not in use](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175829/find-fields-that-are-not-in-use)