Need to identify unused fields in Activity object
As per a requirement I need to add a new field in the Activity object.
Currently Activity object already have 98 fields and maximum it can have 100 fields.
As we are at around limit, we need to identify unused fields and remove those.
As per this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/175832/59842 I am trying to start Salesforce Optimizer but it not loading:

How can I run Salesforce Optmizer?

Have you read the section of thehelp page "analysis could take up to 24 hours"?

This issue has already been raised at known issues. And already been answered here.

Until Salesforce Optimizer is working again and as alternative, you can try SF explorer chrome extension or access it via the web app to find field usage.

From the web app version, login to the Salesforce org and go to object manager.

Search for object by name (Task or Event)




Then click on the object label to see the fields for the object and its usage (percentage of completed field based on number of records on the org)

click on each field to see usage percentage by number of records



Disclaimer : I am not affiliated with this tool nor its owner. It is developed by a trusted source and this can be verified in the help documentation mentioning that the tool is developed by a Program Architect at Salesforce

If no automated processes, batches or API calls are running on this org, you can try making a naive check using SOQL queries - let's assume the field is considered  unused if all records of this objet have this field as null, blank or default value in last X days (like half a year, 180 days). We can use queues like this then:
SELECT Id, CustomField__c FROM Task WHERE CustomField__c = null AND LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:180

You can perform such a query for every Custom Field against every Activity Object, like Task, Events, etc. I'd consider this not being enough to be certain about field deletion, but it can give useful fitting
